# Want to get the stuff centered

Tags: html, css, image

What am I doing wrong here? I want the stuff that's here to be on the middle of the screen, but however I'm trying, I can't get it working..

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.bild {
  padding: 2em 0 0 2em;
}

img {
  max-width: 60%;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-radius: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: block
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25em;
  margin-top: 2.2em;
}

.floatright {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bild">
      <img src="images/jag.jpg" alt="En bild på mig">
      <h1>Välkommen!</h1>
      <span class="floatright">Jag heter Patrik Qvarnström</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can't really get the content centered:

[image: Can't really get the content centered]

Comment: Please give a more detailed description what you see as the problem of the output of your code.

Comment: You will not be able to horizontally center any elements with `float` properties declared. You can embed placeholder images (for the sake of demonstration) at https://placeholder.com/ or http://lorempixel.com/ (if you are unable to use absolute filepaths for any reason)

Comment: Consider finding a way to demonstrate the intended result, or clarifying the question further to receive the answers expected. The initial impression is that you require all elements horizontally centered and that typically results in a stacked layout. If I were to hazard a guess it appears that you want to keep elements floated as they are, but to "group" them and "move" this group to the center of the viewport. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, that sounds to be correct!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* { 
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #wrapper{
      display: table;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 60%;
        padding-top: 1em;
        border-radius: 100px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    .container {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="bild">
            <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" alt="En bild på mig" width="150">
            <div class="container"> 
              <h1>Välkommen!</h1>
              <p class="floatright">Jag heter Patrik Qvarnström</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So you want the image centered and the text an the right side by side the img?

Answer (score 0):

Remove float: left from img and add margin: auto like this:

```css
* { 
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        max-width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    #wrapper {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .bild {
        padding: 2em 0 0 2em;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 60%;
        padding-top: 1em;
        border-radius: 100px;
        display: block;
  margin: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 2em;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 25em;
        margin-top: 2.2em;
    }
    .floatright {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10em;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="bild">
            <img src="temp.PNG" alt="En bild på mig">
            <h1>Välkommen!</h1>
            <span class="floatright">Jag heter Patrik Qvarnström</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Flexbox solution is OK for you - here it is (it's pretty cool for centering and in total):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bild {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bild">
    <img src="https://www.adrln.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/img.png" alt="En bild på mig">
    <h1>Välkommen!</h1>
    <span class="floatright">Jag heter Patrik Qvarnström</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Set width on containing element:** Declare a `width` or `max-width` property on the containing (parent)
   element `.bild`, e.g: `max-width: 55%;` - adjust this value
   accordingly to suit requirements.
2. **Align horizontally center:** Declare the shorthand `margin` property rule with a value of `auto`
   on the containing (parent) element `.bild`, e.g: `margin: auto;` -
   this will allow the containing element to horizontally center.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.bild {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 55%; /* adjust this value accordingly to suit requirements */
  min-width: 425px; /* for the sake of demonstration */
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed; /* for the sake of demonstration */
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 60%;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 2.2em;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bild">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="En bild på mig">
      <h1 class="floatright">Välkommen!</h1>
      <span class="floatright">Jag heter Patrik Qvarnström</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**In Summary:**

- `.bild` is a `div` element
- a `div` element is a *block-level* element (occupies full horizontal
  width, unlike *inline* elements)
- to horizontally center a *block-level* element: **1.** declare a `width`
  property and **2.** declare `margin` property with a value of `auto`
- any element can be made a *block-level* element by declaring
  `display: block`

*Note: the aforementioned techniques will not behave as explained if any `float` properties have been declared, `float` will negate any attempt at horizontal alignment, unless the element in question has been declared as `flex-box` display, e.g: `display: flex`*

**Practical Demonstrations:**
<sub>*For block-level and inline elements*</sub>

- [Horizontal Alignment (Arbitrary Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/vWGbdb) <sup>(CodePen)</sup>
- [Horizontal Alignment (Text Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/BmKMra) <sup>(CodePen)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Taking [P.S.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170607/6127393) a little further with a nested flexbox.
Make both `#wrapper` and `.bild` flexbox containers. The trick here is to make `.bild` an "inflexible" flex item with `flex: 0 0 0;`, I also wrapped the `h1` and `span` elements in a `div` so the `img` and the `div` are the two flex items in the nested flexbox.

See comments in code for more details:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
  /* 
    center child flex-items on the main axis
    (in this case horizontally) 
  */
  justify-content: center; 
}

.bild {
  /*
    we do not want this flex-item to grow or shrink 
    we only want it wide enough to contain it's children
    so flex-basis: 0; makes it as close to zero width as possible
  */
  flex: 0 0 0; /* flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 0; */
  
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em; /* between child flex-items */
  align-items: center; /* on the cross-axis (in this case vertically) */
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.bild>img {
  max-width: 15vw;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.bild span {
  /* 
    .bild wants to be narrow as possible and 
    will force the text to wrap without this
  */
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bild">
    <img src="https://mosmandentistry.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/orionthemes-placeholder-image-2.png" alt="En bild på mig">
    <div>
      <h1>Välkommen!</h1>
      <span>Jag heter Patrik Qvarnström</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/